# repository pattern in ef6 with Interfaces

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, repository-pattern

aLets have a simple scenario:

```
public interface IMember
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MemberEF6Impl : IMember
{
    //some annotations...
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MemberVMImpl : IMember
{
    //some other annotations...
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //some functionality...
}
```

I have two concrete implementation of all interfaces in our programm. One implementation especially for database migration, one for our viewmodel. Now I want to realize the **factory-pattern** and  add one more interface and two more concrete implementations of it:

```
public interface IRepository
{
    ICollection<TModel> GetAll<TModel>() where TModel : class;
    //some more functionality...
}


public class RepositoryEF6Impl : IRepository
{
    protected readonly DbContext context;

    public RepositoryEF6Impl(DbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }
    public ICollection<TModel> GetAll<TModel>() where TModel : class
    {
         return context.Set<TModel>().ToList();
    }
    //some more functionality...
}
```

Now I can use the repository straight forward as follows:

```
IRepository repo = new RepositoryEF6Impl(context);
repo.GetAll<MemberEF6Impl>();
```

So far so good. But I want to use it this way:

```
IRepository repo = new RepositoryEF6Impl(context);
repo.GetAll<IMember>(); //note the difference
```

The problem is that in the database there is no IMember, but a MemberEF6Impl.

Why I want to use it this way:

Because we have different concrete classes for databse stuff and for viewmodel, I have to create a 2nd repository as well for viewmodel, which is only a layer between the concrete VMImpl class and the EF6 repository.

```
public class RepositoryVMImpl : IRepository
{
    protected readonly IRepository repository;

    public RepositoryVMImpl(IRepository repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public ICollection<TModel> GetAll<TModel>() where TModel : class
    {
        return repository.GetAll<TModel>();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to achive this?

Comment: The view model, or dto, should ideally be decoupled from your domain logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to use single repository, but with some method overloading for projecting the requested generic type.

Method overload:

```
public ICollection<TProjection> GetAll<TModel, TProjection>(Expression<Func<TModel, TProjection>> projection)
{
      return context.Set<TModel>().Select(projection).ToList();
}
```

then you can use the method like this, which will give control over the return type.

```
repository.GetAll<MemberEF6Impl, IMember>(memberEF => new MemberVMImp { ... })
```

If you still need the EF entity model as a result type you can use your current method:

```
repository.GetAll<MemberEF6Impl>();
```

More information about EF projections: https://www.tektutorialshub.com/projection-queries-entity-framework/

Also [Automapper](http://automapper.org/) provides such functionality - it can save you some time. You should check it out.